# Set table borders in Google Document with Google Script App

Tags: google-apps-script, google-api, google-docs, google-docs-api

I am trying to alter table borders with Google Script App (and Google API). I based my code on this post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72254191/edit-tables-border-of-doc-with-apps-script), but without success.

I am getting these two errors:

Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'body')
Invalid requests[0].updateTableCellStyle: The provided table start location is invalid.

Could you help me?

```
function susbstituirTabela (docID, arrayTabela, texttofind){
    const doc = DocumentApp.openById(docID);
    var body = doc.getBody();
    var rgel = body.findText(texttofind);
    var element = rgel.getElement();
    var childIndex = body.getChildIndex(element.getParent());
    var arrayFinal = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < arrayTabela.length; i++) {
      let t = [];
      if (i == 0) {
        t.push('Vencimento');
        t.push('N.');
        t.push('Valor');
        t.push('Saldo')
      } else {
        if (arrayTabela[i].vencimento != "") {
          t.push(arrayTabela[i].vencimento.split(',')[0]);
        }
        t.push(arrayTabela[i].nparcela);
        t.push(arrayTabela[i].parcela.toLocaleString('pt-BR', { style: 'currency', currency: 'BRL' }));
        t.push(arrayTabela[i].saldo.toLocaleString('pt-BR', { style: 'currency', currency: 'BRL' }));
        arrayFinal.push(t);
    }}

    body.getChild(childIndex).asText().setText('');
    var tab = body.insertTable(childIndex,arrayFinal);
    tab.setColumnWidth(0, 60);
    tab.setColumnWidth(1, 30);
    tab.setColumnWidth(2, 80);
    tab.setColumnWidth(3, 100);


    var table = body.getTables()[0]; // Please set your table.
    Logger.log(table);
    var index = body.getChildIndex(table);
    var tableIndex = Docs.Documents.doc.body.content[index + 1].startIndex;
    doc.saveAndClose();
    var requests = [{ updateTableCellStyle: { tableCellStyle: { borderRight: { dashStyle: "SOLID", width: { magnitude: 0, unit: "PT" }, color: { color: { rgbColor: { red: 0 } } } }, borderLeft: { dashStyle: "SOLID", width: { magnitude: 0, unit: "PT" }, color: { color: { rgbColor: { red: 0 } } } } }, tableStartLocation: { tableIndex }, fields: "borderRight,borderLeft" } }];

    Docs.Documents.batchUpdate({ requests }, docID);

}
```

**UPDATE**
Changed the code as follows and got the following error:

requests[0].update_table_cell_style.table_start_location': Cannot find field.

```
var tableIndex = Docs.Documents.get(docID).body.content[index + 1].startIndex;
doc.saveAndClose();
var requests = [{ updateTableCellStyle: { tableCellStyle: { borderRight: { dashStyle: "SOLID", width: { magnitude: 0, unit: "PT" }, color: { color: { rgbColor: { red: 0 } } } }, borderLeft: { dashStyle: "SOLID", width: { magnitude: 0, unit: "PT" }, color: { color: { rgbColor: { red: 0 } } } } }, tableStartLocation: { tableIndex }, fields: "borderRight,borderLeft" } }];

Docs.Documents.batchUpdate({ requests }, docID);
```

Comment: It seems that the URL of `here` of `I based my code on this post here` is `https://stackoverflow.com/`. Can you update it?

Comment: Sorry about that. Done.

Comment: Thank you for updating it. When I saw it, I noticed that your referenced answer is my answer. I apologize that my answer was not useful in your situation. About your question, I proposed a modification point as an answer. Please confirm it. If that was not useful, I apologize again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Modification points:

- About `var tableIndex = Docs.Documents.doc.body.content[index + 1].startIndex;`, I think that `Docs.Documents` has no property of `doc`.
- About the following change, in this case, there is no property of `tableIndex`. By this, an error like `requests[0].update_table_cell_style.table_start_location': Cannot find field.` occurs.

  ```js
  var tableIndex = Docs.Documents.get(docID).body.content[index + 1].startIndex;
  doc.saveAndClose();
  var requests = [{ updateTableCellStyle: { tableCellStyle: { borderRight: { dashStyle: "SOLID", width: { magnitude: 0, unit: "PT" }, color: { color: { rgbColor: { red: 0 } } } }, borderLeft: { dashStyle: "SOLID", width: { magnitude: 0, unit: "PT" }, color: { color: { rgbColor: { red: 0 } } } } }, tableStartLocation: { tableIndex }, fields: "borderRight,borderLeft" } }];

  Docs.Documents.batchUpdate({ requests }, docID);
  ```
- I think that `doc.saveAndClose()` is required to be moved before `Docs.Documents.get`.

When these points are reflected in your script, it becomes as follows.

#### From:

```js
var table = body.getTables()[0]; // Please set your table.
Logger.log(table);
var index = body.getChildIndex(table);
var tableIndex = Docs.Documents.doc.body.content[index + 1].startIndex;
doc.saveAndClose();
var requests = [{ updateTableCellStyle: { tableCellStyle: { borderRight: { dashStyle: "SOLID", width: { magnitude: 0, unit: "PT" }, color: { color: { rgbColor: { red: 0 } } } }, borderLeft: { dashStyle: "SOLID", width: { magnitude: 0, unit: "PT" }, color: { color: { rgbColor: { red: 0 } } } } }, tableStartLocation: { tableIndex }, fields: "borderRight,borderLeft" } }];

Docs.Documents.batchUpdate({ requests }, docID);
```

#### To:

```js
var table = body.getTables()[0];
doc.saveAndClose();
var index = Docs.Documents.get(docID).body.content[body.getChildIndex(table) + 1].startIndex;
var requests = [{ updateTableCellStyle: { tableCellStyle: { borderRight: { dashStyle: "SOLID", width: { magnitude: 0, unit: "PT" }, color: { color: { rgbColor: { red: 0 } } } }, borderLeft: { dashStyle: "SOLID", width: { magnitude: 0, unit: "PT" }, color: { color: { rgbColor: { red: 0 } } } } }, tableStartLocation: { index }, fields: "borderRight,borderLeft" } }];
Docs.Documents.batchUpdate({ requests }, docID);
```

#### Note:

- In this modification, it supposes that your values of `docID, arrayTabela, texttofind` are valid values. Please be careful about this.

#### References:

- [Method: documents.batchUpdate](https://developers.google.com/docs/api/reference/rest/v1/documents/batchUpdate)
- UpdateTableCellStyleRequest

Comment: Tanaike, thank, the code just ran without problems. The issue now is that the table was not formatted accordingly. This is the only table created on the document, shouldn`t ir run?

Comment: @Coelho Thank you for replying. About `thank, the code just ran without problems.`, I understood that your issue was resolved. About your new question of `The issue now is that the table was not formatted accordingly. This is the only table created on the document, shouldn`t ir run?`, I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand your new question. Can I ask you about the detail of it?

Comment: Thank you very much for your response. The problem is that the table which borders I wanted to set was not formatted, it was the same with the default borders. So i am thinking the code is not "finding" my table or not formatting it.

Comment: @Coelho Thank you for replying. I have to apologize for my poor English skill again. Unfortunately, I cannot understand `The problem is that the table which borders I wanted to set was not formatted, it was the same with the default borders. So i am thinking the code is not "finding" my table or not formatting it.`. I could resolve your question. But, I deeply apologize that I cannot resolve your new question soon.

Comment: Sure, will do that. Thank you very much!