# Formatting table borders of Google Document with Google Script App not working

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-docs

I was getting problemas with my code to format the borders of a table in a Google Document and
Tanaike helpe me [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76263365/set-table-borders-in-google-document-with-google-script-app)

The problem now is that my table is not getting formatted, it is as if the code doesn`t find the table. It remains with the default borders. Could you help me?

```
function susbstituirTabela (docID, arrayTabela, texttofind){
    const doc = DocumentApp.openById(docID);
    var body = doc.getBody();
    var rgel = body.findText(texttofind);
    var element = rgel.getElement();
    var childIndex = body.getChildIndex(element.getParent());
    var arrayFinal = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < arrayTabela.length; i++) {
      let t = [];
      if (i == 0) {
        t.push('Vencimento');
        t.push('N.');
        t.push('Valor');
        t.push('Saldo')
      } else {
        if (arrayTabela[i].vencimento != "") {
          t.push(arrayTabela[i].vencimento.split(',')[0]);
        }
        t.push(arrayTabela[i].nparcela);
        t.push(arrayTabela[i].parcela.toLocaleString('pt-BR', { style: 'currency', currency: 'BRL' }));
        t.push(arrayTabela[i].saldo.toLocaleString('pt-BR', { style: 'currency', currency: 'BRL' }));
        arrayFinal.push(t);
    }}
  //   var t = [
  //   ['Vencimento', 'N. Parcela', 'Valor'],
  //   ['Row 2, Cell 1', 'Row 2, Cell 2']
  // ];
    body.getChild(childIndex).asText().setText('');
    var tab = body.insertTable(childIndex,arrayFinal);
    tab.setColumnWidth(0, 60);
    tab.setColumnWidth(1, 30);
    tab.setColumnWidth(2, 80);
    tab.setColumnWidth(3, 100);


    var table = body.getTables()[0];
    doc.saveAndClose();
    var index = Docs.Documents.get(docID).body.content[body.getChildIndex(table) + 1].startIndex;
    var requests = [{ updateTableCellStyle: { tableCellStyle: { borderRight: { dashStyle: "SOLID", width: { magnitude: 0, unit: "PT" }, color: { color: { rgbColor: { red: 0 } } } }, borderLeft: { dashStyle: "SOLID", width: { magnitude: 0, unit: "PT" }, color: { color: { rgbColor: { red: 0 } } } } }, tableStartLocation: { index }, fields: "borderRight,borderLeft" } }];
    Docs.Documents.batchUpdate({ requests }, docID);

}
```

Comment: Can I ask you about the detail of `The problem now is that my table is not getting formatted, it is as if the code doesn`t find the table.`. For example, can you provide the sample input and output situations you expect? I would like to correctly understand your question and support it.

Answer (score 0):

You need to change your request.

```
width: { magnitude: 0, unit: "PT" }  // means no thickness

color: { color: { rgbColor: { red: 0 } } } }  // means no color
```

Try the following:

```
let requests = [
    { updateTableCellStyle: 
      { tableCellStyle: 
        { borderRight: 
          { dashStyle: "SOLID", 
            width: { magnitude: 1, unit: "PT" }, 
            color: 
              { color: 
                { rgbColor: { red: 1, green: 0, blue: 0 } } 
              }
          }, 
          borderLeft: 
            { dashStyle: "SOLID", 
              width: 
                { magnitude: 1, unit: "PT" }, 
              color: 
                { color: { rgbColor: { red: 1, green: 0, blue: 0 } } } 
            } 
        }, 
        tableStartLocation: { index: index }, 
        fields: "borderRight,borderLeft" } 
    }
  ];
```

Comment: Unfortunatelly got this error: GoogleJsonResponseException: API call to docs.documents.batchUpdate failed with error: Invalid JSON payload received. Unknown name "": Root element must be a message.

Comment: I can only tell you, I run it in a text script and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks all for your help. Got it working like this:

```
const index = body.getChildIndex(tab);
const documentId = doc.getId();
doc.saveAndClose();
const tableStart = Docs.Documents.get(documentId).body.content[index + 1].startIndex;
const tempStyledel = {width: {magnitude :0, unit: "PT"}, dashStyle: "SOLID", color: {color: {rgbColor: {red: 0.5, green : 0.5, blue: 0.5}}}};
const tempStyle = {width: {magnitude :0.75, unit: "PT"}, dashStyle: "SOLID", color: {color: {rgbColor: {red: 0.5, green : 0.5, blue: 0.5}}}};
const resource = {requests: [
  {
    "pinTableHeaderRows": { // Set pinned rows
      "tableStartLocation": {
        "index": tableStart
        },
      "pinnedHeaderRowsCount": 1
    }
  },
  {updateTableCellStyle: {
    tableStartLocation: {index: tableStart},
    tableCellStyle: {borderTop: tempStyle, borderBottom: tempStyle, borderLeft: tempStyledel, borderRight: tempStyledel},
    fields: "borderTop,borderBottom,borderLeft,borderRight"
  }},
  {updateTableCellStyle: {
    tableRange: {
      tableCellLocation: {tableStartLocation: {index: tableStart}, rowIndex: 0, columnIndex: 0}, rowSpan: 1, columnSpan: 4},
      tableCellStyle: {
        backgroundColor: { color: { rgbColor: {red: 0.1098, green: 0.1490, blue: 0.3294 }}}
        // borderRight: {dashStyle: "SOLID", width: {magnitude: 3, unit: "PT"}, color: {color: {rgbColor: {red: 1}}}}
      },
      fields: "backgroundColor"
  }}
]};
Docs.Documents.batchUpdate(resource, documentId);
```